# How can I get a docker client with docker-py inside a gitlab-ci docker container?

Tags: gitlab-ci, dockerpy

On my local dev machine I use `docker.from_env(version=auto)` ([docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py)) to get a docker client without any issues. If I run the same statement inside a `gitlab-ci` job which run inside a docker container (or with `gitlab-runner exec docker ...` during local debugging) to get a docker client I get a `DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))`. How can I get a docker client with `docker-py` inside a `gitlab-ci` job which runs inside a docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to build and deploy your own runner with the following binding '/var/sock/docker.sock:/var/sock/docker.sock.

Comment: It turned out that this was the issue. Thx.

Comment: Did you wind up spinning up your own runner for this ? If so do you mind sharing your config ?

Comment: I think that's IP of the company I am working for. But as you said it's just about exposing `/var/sock/docker.sock` to the parent context.

Comment: Hint: For local debugging of gitlab-ci job refer to https://forum.gitlab.com/t/set-default-arguments-for-gitlab-runner-exec-docker/5485